# ros2 launch packages path

Tags: ros2, roslaunch, ros-bouncy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm quite confused by how ROS2 manages packages and package locations.

In ROS1, I would compile my nodes with a `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` like `$HOME/ros-dev` and install them there, then source `$HOME/ros-dev/setup.bash` (or manually set `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$HOME/ros-dev/share`), and everyone was happy: `ros run` & `roslaunch` would find my packages, and I could compile other packages with cmake finding the dependencies on the installed one without trouble.

Now, ROS2/`ament` got rid of `setup.bash`. Fine, I can certainly live with that. But if I create a launch file with the new python framework (btw, this framework is awfully verbose -- I certainly liked the XML launch files better, even though it was XML), how is `ros2 launch my_launch_file.py` supposed to know where my packages are located?

By default, it looks for packages in `/opt/ros/bouncy`. I can set `AMENT_PREFIX_PATH` to my install prefix, but it doesn't seem to be able to find the packages/nodes (I've tried as well `$PREFIX/lib` and `$PREFIX/share` without much success).

And beyond that specific issue, what is the correct way of telling ROS2 where the packages are installed? Setting `AMENT_PREFIX_PATH` in my `.bashrc` with a list of possible install prefixes? (in that case, it would have been nice to reuse `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` whose name is clearer)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/304960/ros2-launch-packages-path/) by [severin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2119/severin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 240 on 2018-10-05

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-10-08**:
Perhaps it is a typo, but `ros2 launch my_launch_file.py` would not work unless `my_launch_file.py` is in the current directory. Something like `ros2 launch my_package my_launch_file.py` would work by finding where `my_package` is installed and locating the launch file from there.

**Comment by [severin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2119/severin/) on 2018-10-09**:
@William in that particular case, the launch file was indeed in the current directory, but yes, in general you are right :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Following the [Colcon Tutorial](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/wiki/Colcon-Tutorial#source-the-environment), after building a custom package we can still find a `setup.bash` (and a `local_setup.bash`) in the `install` directory of the workspace. Sourcing one of these will populate `AMENT_PREFIX_PATH` and commands like `ros2 launch` should be able to locate your packages.

If my workspace is located at `~/ros2_ws`, then I should be able to do `source ~/ros2_ws/install/local_setup.bash` after building.

---

Originally posted by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) with karma: 1870 on 2018-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-10-08**:
I'll add that it is a specific choice to not have something like the `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` (which would find packages even if they have not been built yet by searching) and instead require all packages to be installed before our tools can find them (allowing us to avoid all expensive searching).

**Comment by [severin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2119/severin/) on 2018-10-09**:
But then the question surely is: why does `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` find non-build packages? I've only ever pointed my `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` to my *install* directories (and I thought it was the way it was supposed to be done...)

**Comment by [severin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2119/severin/) on 2018-10-09**:
Thanks @jacobperron. In ROS1, the traditional, non-ROS-specific, `cd build && cmake .. && make && make install` sequence works great and install a `setup.sh` in `$CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`. I'd rather do the same with ROS2 instead of using 'magic' tools like `colcon`.

**Comment by [Zhoulai Fu](https://answers.ros.org/users/34164/zhoulai-fu/) on 2018-12-22**:
@severin Totally Agreed! Inventing a new name "colcon", "ament", or what ever machin or truc,  just makes  ROS2 harder to use, wasting many people's time.  I wish that ROS3 would come with a more standard build-system that would be welcoming to new contributors.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-12-26**:
@Zhoulai Fu if you know an existing build system which satisfies all the requirements of ROS (processing federally dev. pkgs in a single invocation, support for CMake/Python pkgs etc., working across all target platforms, supporting cross compilation) please feel free to suggest it.

**Comment by [Zhoulai Fu](https://answers.ros.org/users/34164/zhoulai-fu/) on 2019-03-25**:
@Dirk Thomas I do not know, but what were the challenges for using only a traditional CMake-based build system (that works well on the Clang project, for example) ?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2019-03-25**:
`ament_cmake` is plain CMake plus helper functions you can either use or decide to implement yourself. There is nothing non-CMake in `ament_cmake`. You can absolutely write a package in vanilla CMake (if you prefer to do everything by hand). Also CMake does not address the question of Python packages where you want to use something native to Python development (which is `setup.py` / `setuptools`). And CMake doesn't scale well to building numerous CMake packages efficiently - therefore we use a build tool which invoked `cmake` for each package in the right order.

**Comment by [Zhoulai Fu](https://answers.ros.org/users/34164/zhoulai-fu/) on 2019-03-29**:
Now I see that "ament_cmake"  is a CMake wrapper that helps overcome CMake efficiency issues and issues related to python setuptools. Thank you very much for your detailed explanation, @Dirk Thomas.

**Comment by [felixf4xu](https://answers.ros.org/users/120001/felixf4xu/) on 2022-10-06**:
No, it's not cmake wrappers/helper funstions. If it is, we should be able to run something line "cmake .." just like any other cmake projects to config and build, but we cann't! The `ament_cmake` things must be run by `colcon`  and the additional `source ..` cmd, which are absolutely aliens to native cmake!!